# Work flow formula for increase and decrease value

Tags: workflow

I want to create workflow and i want formula to be like is, When Property_status__c = Unqualified, Watch__c = True, Current_price_list__c = --Decrease, Top__c = ++increase, City__c = Chicago.

For example,If Current List Price goes down And If Top Property Price goes up and meet other criteria, at that time workflow should fire.

In this one i am not sure how can i use increase and decrease for any field?

Any help please.

Comment: The issue is how would you keep track of old value.

Comment: Cant i do like if the value goes down from current value(whatever it is) then workflow will fire.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right syntax, but you could try to create the workflow when the formula evaluates to true. It would look something like this, without having to create any additional fields.

```
AND(
(Property_status__c == "Unqualified"),
(Watch__c == "True"),
(City__c == "Chicago" ),
(ISCHANGED(Current_price_list__c )),
(Current_price_list__c-(PRIORVALUE(Current_price_list__c))<0),
(ISCHANGED(Top__c)),
(Top__c-(PRIORVALUE(Top__c))>0)
)
```

Comment: Tried that,but its not working.

Comment: are all your described fields of type 'Text' , because if they are of type picklist value you'd have to use the following syntax `IsPickValue(MyField__c, "Case1")`

Comment: What about currency field? Current_price_list__c is a currency field.

Comment: the currency shouldn't be a problem as it will interpret the value when performing the calculations as far as I'm concerned. try To eliminate 1 condition at a time and see where is failing. From a logical perspective the workflow should work

Comment: AND(
(IsPickValue(Property_status__c, "Unqualified")),
( Watch__c == "True"),
(City__c == "Chicago" ),
(ISCHANGED(Current_price_list__c )),
(Current_price_list__c -(PRIORVALUE(Current_price_list__c ))<0),
)

Comment: I am trying this one but getting Syntax error. Found ')'. Not sure why getting this error. syntax looks good to me.

Comment: yuo have an additional comma at the end, remove it

Comment: Error: Field REOHQ__REOHQ_Property_Style__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions. <a href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds('/HelpAndTrainingDoor?loc=help&target=tips_on_building_formulas.htm%23picklists_and_msps&section=Customizing', 'Help', 1024, 768, 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no', false, false);">Tell me more</a>

Comment: Any idea about this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39086/discussion-between-salesfor-dev-and-marc-zaharescu).

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a new field for the previous price. and have a workflow that will copy the value into this field when the price changes. then on your other workflow you can do if old price is larger than new or if old price is smaller than new fire the workflow.

Comment: Thats what i also thought, but how can i store previous value in other field?

Comment: you will need a workflow for the price with ISCHANGED(Field name) and then workflow can use update field and update the new field (old price) with the price.

Comment: I think directly using PRIORVALUE() is much better choice rather then creating new field.See @marc answer.